# Minimum number of steps required to convert A to B

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I have recently participated in a coding contest where one of the problems was as follows:

Given two integers X and Y, find the minimum number of steps required to convert X to Y. You can perform the following operations any number of times in any order:

1) Divide X by any integer A,     2)Multiply X by any integer B.

Example: If X=15 and Y=10, then first multiply X by 2 which gives 30 and then divide 30 by 3 to get Y(i.e.,10). So the minimum no. of steps in this case is 2.

I have no idea how to solve it.

Comment: division/multiplication order does not matter think of prime factors, so in one multiplication you can add missing prime factors, in one division remove excess ones

Comment: I guess some details are missing. If not, divide by X and multiply by Y !

Comment: Sorry.. i have edited the question to make it more clear now..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated, the minimum number of steps is no greater than two: you can always choose A=X and B=Y so that `X/A*B = X/X*Y = Y`.

The only times you can do better than this are the following:

1. if X % Y = 0, the minimum number of steps is 1 and the correct choice is A=(X/Y).
2. if Y % X = 0, the minimum number of steps is 1 and the correct choice is B=(Y/X).
3. if X = Y, the minimum number of steps is 0 as no multiplications or divisions are required at all.

Comment: Sorry you misunderstood the problem.. i didn't mean it. You can perform those two operations any number of times meaning the min no. of steps can be greater than 2.

Comment: @Saif Can you give an example of integers X, Y where the minimum number of steps is greater than two? If so, can you explain why the choice A=X, B=Y is not a two-step solution?

Comment: OMG!! Thank you so much..I got it now. Yes, the minimum number of steps cant be greater than 2. What I meant by "misunderstood" was that you said "As stated" in the beginning, but it was not stated in the question that min. no. of steps can't be greater than 2(it was just in an example). I was correcting that. Anyway thank you!!